# Return vector from C++ to Python without copying using SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am trying to build a python module in C++ using SWIG. I have the following code:

```
struct ContainerElement
{
    uint8_t i;
    double d;
    double d2;
};

class Container
{
private:
    std::vector<uint8_t> ints;
    std::vector<double> doubles;
    std::vector<double> doubles2;

public:

    std::vector<uint8_t>& getInts() { return ints; }
    std::vector<double>& getDoubles() { return doubles; }
    std::vector<double>& getDoubles2() { return doubles2; }

    void addElement(ContainerElement element)
    {
        ints.emplace_back(element.i);
        doubles.emplace_back(element.d);
        doubles2.emplace_back(element.d2);
    }
};

void fillContainer(Container& container)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1e6; ++i)
    {
        container.addElement({(uint8_t)i, (double)i,(double)i });
    }
}
```

And an interface file container.i:

```
%module container

%{
#include "container.h"
%}

%include container.h
%include "std_vector.i"
%include "stdint.i"

%template(DoubleVector) std::vector<double>;
%template(IntVector) std::vector<uint8_t>;
```

When I call this code in python:

```
import psutil
import os
import container
import numpy as np

print(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss)

cont = container.Container()
container.fillContainer(cont)

print(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss)

a = np.array(cont.getInts(), copy=False)
b = np.array(cont.getDoubles(), copy=False)
c = np.array(cont.getDoubles2(), copy=False)

print(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss)
```

This works, however when I check the memory usage of the program (using `psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss`) it seems to make a copy when I call the functions `getInts, getDoubles` and `getDoubles2`. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy can't do anything with a vector object: it needs the underlying memory. The easiest would have been if you could call the vector's data(), but SWIG does not expose that function. Just for reference, here's cppyy (http://cppyy.org) which does expose data() to show that that simply works, i.e. that the problem isn't with numpy:

```
import cppyy
cppyy.include("container.h")
import psutil
import os
import numpy as np

print(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss)

cont = cppyy.gbl.Container()
cppyy.gbl.fillContainer(cont) 

print(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss)

a = np.array(cont.getInts().data(), copy=False)
b = np.array(cont.getDoubles().data(), copy=False)
c = np.array(cont.getDoubles2().data(), copy=False)

print(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss)
```

(Of course cppyy takes more memory straight of the bat, b/c it loads LLVM; incrementally it will win however.)

So first you need to expose that data() call through SWIG and then I think it's easiest to add a python layering on top of that, to make the usage clean to client code (with the caveat that you may run into memory issues if the original vectors get deleted or resized, but that's always a problem for any code that does not copy).

Start by modifying your container code:

```
// include the numpy header; find its location with:
//    python -c 'import numpy; print(numpy.get_include())'
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"

// ... rest of your container code here ...

// data to numpy helpers
PyObject* vec_data_uint8_t(std::vector<uint8_t>& d) {
    import_array();
    npy_intp dims[] = {(npy_intp)d.size()};
    npy_intp strides[] = {sizeof(std::vector<uint8_t>::value_type)};
    return PyArray_NewFromDescr(&PyArray_Type, PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_UINT8),
        1, dims, strides, d.data(), NPY_ARRAY_C_CONTIGUOUS, nullptr);
}

PyObject* vec_data_double(std::vector<double>& d) {
    import_array();
    npy_intp dims[] = {(npy_intp)d.size()};
    npy_intp strides[] = {sizeof(std::vector<double>::value_type)};
    return PyArray_NewFromDescr(&PyArray_Type, PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_DOUBLE),
        1, dims, strides, d.data(), NPY_ARRAY_C_CONTIGUOUS, nullptr);
}
```

SWIG will automatically pick those up, so container.i is fine. Now add a mycontainer.py helper module like so:

```
import numpy
from container import *

IntVector.__array__ = vec_data_uint8_t
DoubleVector.__array__ = vec_data_double
```

and in your original python code, replace `import container` with:

```
import mycontainer as container
```

Now you can use your vectors as always but when handed to a numpy array, the custom `__array__` function will be called, given it access to the internal data and will not copy if `copy=False`.

Comment: That seems like a very complicated solution for this problem. Not sure if that is the way to go. I could change the C++ code to not use vectors, but instead use pointers. Would that provide a more simple solution do you think?

Comment: Up to an extent: the complexity isn't going away. If you expose only the pointer, you also need to provide the length somehow, eg. with a getIntsSize() function that the client code then needs to provide to the numpy array. SWIG will take care of the type. (In the case of cppyy, all this is done under the hood b/c the result of the call to `data()` returns a low level memory view that implements the buffer protocol.)